# Plesk CP with a linux cluster

Tags: linux, cluster

I've managed to start a project where i should be implementing a linux cluster mainly for webhosting.
I need to run plesk on top of that cluster in order to provide cps to customers but there seems to be a problem with plesk:

I was planning to manage authentications, user dirs etc. trough ldap and have a glusterFS as SAN but apparently plesk doesn't support that sort of backend... Hours of research and testing did not lead me to any direction (other than not using plesk), but im sure that there are clustered plesk installations out there so im wondering how did they overcome plesk limitations.

If you have any info or tips for having an Apache cluster on top of plesk would much appreciate

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk isn't designed to operate in a cluster, nor is cPanel or many other control panels.

There are only really a few which are, [InterWorx](http://www.interworx.com) comes to mind.

We actually use cPanel in a clustered configuration - but we had to write quite a few scripts to support the replication of configuration files and obviously set up the base file replication/failover/load balancing itself.

Comment: Sounds bad... do you have any idea about how to build at least a HA solution adopting plesk?

Comment: I wouldn't bother, Plesk is a behemoth and a huge proportion of its functionality really doesn't apply to a cluster, other than distributed web nodes. So nail your replication, then write some scripts to re-distribute Apache configs, DNS zones etc/ all you'll be sorted

Comment: It's not that easy as my cluster should be of around 30-50 machines, i don't even know if plesk will be able to handle that load of data. Up front i really need LDAP to be the central point and seems that the mandatory requirement is plesk CP... So i guess there is no viable solution for my issue, other than putting virtualized environment on the bottom of independent system images.

Comment: I cannot really understand what the deployment is supposed to be here, with 50 machines - using a control panel designed for single-server configuration. Is it for re-selling hosting/a single website etc ... Why do you need LDAP? You haven't provided nearly enough detail to provide a ***useful*** answer, but my answer still stands, Plesk isn't the appropriate choice as a clustered CP.